# Keeping trailing zeros

Tags: r, math, rounding

I would like to keep trailing zeros, for example, if I type:

```
round(5.2, 3)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
5.200
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If this is for printing purposes, `sprintf` is what you are after:

```
> sprintf("%.3f", round(5.2,3))
[1] "5.200"
```

See `?sprintf` for formatting details.

Comment: @Chase: Is there the possibility to output a numeric value instead of a character???

Comment: @Marco: I think no, a numeric value does not have trailing zeros.

Comment: @Marco `5.2` == `5.200` they are the same number, the only difference is how the number is represented as a String

Comment: @tim_yates: Yes, of course this is the same. The reason why I was wondering is, as it was suspected, is printing purpose.

Comment: If it's not for printing purposes what could be used instead of `sprintf(...)`?

Comment: @rnorouzian then we use as is: `5.2`.

Answer (score 71):

When you print it out, you should be able to do:

```
formatC( round( 5.2, 3 ), format='f', digits=3 )
```

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry, I cannot accept more than one answer. I have chosen to accept the previous one since Chase has a lower reputation score. However, your solution is very good as well.
Thank you again!

Comment: How about something that works both for printing and non-printing purposes?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Is there anything that could be changed using 'options()' in order to keep trailing zeros? I understand 5.2 == 5.200 but, in my case, for visual consitency it would be nice to keep trailing zeros. Since I am using annotate  with 'parse=T' a string such as provided by 'formatC' isn't enough.

Comment: Previously, I rounded like that but stopped because I thought there was an unnecessary step with the round() function. Do you remember why we are/were doing this:
formatC(round( 5.455, 2), format='f', digits=2 )
and not this:
formatC(5.455, format='f', digits=2 )
It seems as if both are rounding according to the IEEE standard (next even number).