# Rounding a very small number in character format

Tags: r, rounding

I have a very small number like 1.466013e-65,
I want to round it to 3 decimals left while keeping all the 0s, here is the code I used:

```
round(1.466013e-65,3)
```

this will get me 0, but I want it to be 0.000.
How to do it?

Comment: You want `0.000` to be character?

Comment: But it still be equal to 0.

Comment: Yes, I just want it to be in this format

Comment: It would come as a character I guess like `"0.000"`

Comment: Yeah, @PoGibas, I guess it doesn't make too much sense, I will use a character, thank you!

Comment: And thank you!@suchait

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458729/keeping-trailing-zeros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with character, then you can do it using:-

```
sprintf("%.3f", round(1.466013e-65, 3))
[1] "0.000"
```

Comment: while doing `sprintf()` the formatting will be done so no need to round. Just do `sprintf("%.3f",1.466013e-65)`

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that.