# Compare_DF in R truncating trailing zero

Tags: r, compare

I have two dataframes:

`df1`

```
score id
59.09  1
65.27  2
65.05  3
60.15  4
65.30  5
65.61  6
59.21  7
59.70  8
```

And the other dataframe

```
df2

score  id
59.10  1
65.27  2
65.05  3
60.15  4
65.30  5
65.62  6
59.21  7
59.70  8
```

Now when I use compare_df and output it dropped the trailing 0 in `df2`score` 59.10.

[image]

I need this trailing zero to be always displayed.

I have a contraint to use compareDF only.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458729/keeping-trailing-zeros

Comment: ok, so to give a background to you, df1 has scores round to 2 decimal places (from 3) , so df1 is after rounding and it looks fine.The only issue is after i apply the compareDF function.Hope it clears the problem.

Comment: Can you raise an issue with a reprex in the Github repo here? - https://github.com/alexsanjoseph/compareDF - I can take a look at it